# Why can't a Lua table be initialized with a table as one of its keys?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Why does this print `bar` and `baz`, like it is supposed to:

```
local foo = {}
foo[ { "bar", "baz" } ] = 42

for k1, v1 in pairs(foo) do
  for k2, v2 in pairs(k1) do
    print(v2)
  end
end
```

While initializing the `foo` table with the `{ "bar", "baz" }` table as its key directly gives the error `input:1: '}' expected near '='`, at least on the [Lua demo website](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)?:

```
local foo = { { "bar", "baz" } = 42 }

for k1, v1 in pairs(foo) do
  for k2, v2 in pairs(k1) do
    print(v2)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the table constructor, use `[]` to surround the key:

```
local foo = { [{ "bar", "baz" }] = 42 }
--            ^                ^
```

Refer to [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual 3.4.9 - Table Constructors](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.9). You can only leave out the square brackets around a key if it is a Lua identifier (name).